# How can I call a function component with a number value from another component?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a functions component which I pass on to another component. This should then call this function component with a parameter after a button is clicked. However, I get a type error

NewProduct.tsx:

```
const removePreviewImage = (index: number): void | never => {
 const copy = [...preview];
 copy.splice(index, 1);
 setPreview(copy);
};


{preview && preview.map((image, index) => (

<div className="absolute top-2 right-2 bg-slate-500 z-50 rounded-full p-2 text-white group">
  {removePreviewImage && index && (
     <DeleteFromPreview removePreviewImage={removePreviewImage} index={index}/>
   )}
</div>

...

)}
```

DeleteFromPreview.tsx:

```
import { TrashIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import React from "react";

interface RemoveImage{
 removePreviewImage: (index: number) => void;
 index: number;
}

export default function DeleteFromPreview({
 removePreviewImage,
 index,
}: RemoveImage) {

return (
  <TrashIcon
  className="h-8 group-hover:cursor-pointer"
  onClick={() => removePreviewImage(index)}/>
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

It doesn't work that way either.

```
const removePreviewImage = (index: number): void => {
 const copy = [...preview];

 copy.splice(index, 1);
 setPreview(copy);
};
```

[image]

> Property 'removePreviewImage' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type '(index: number) => void' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: Why do you have `never` in return type? Try to remove `| never` and see if the error still occurs

Comment: Yes, the error remains even after removing never

Comment: I can't reproduce the error [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAxa8N)